# Getting corrupted word document when using FileSaver and Blob in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, blob, filesaver.js

I am using angular-file saver service https://github.com/alferov/angular-file-saver for downloading files. Download is good but when try to open word document I am getting file is corrupted and word cannot open it and if put my api directly in browser file is good when I open it so I suppose blob is doing something for this issue... For .txt files I am not getting corrupted it is good only for .docx and for .jpeg or .png. Below is my short code for downloading files.

```
function downloadDocument(fileId, fileName, documentExt) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            var id = encodeURIComponent(fileId);
            Restangular.one('download?fileId=' + id).get().then(function(data) {
                var file = new Blob([data]);
                if (documentExt && documentExt !== 'undefined') {
                    FileSaver.saveAs(file, fileName + '.' + documentExt);
                }
                else {
                    FileSaver.saveAs(file, fileName);
                }
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use give below code to save your file--

```
function downloadDocument(fileId, fileName, documentExt) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            var id = encodeURIComponent(fileId);
            Restangular.one('download?fileId=' + id).get().then(function(data) {
                // try to use data.data or data in blob object
                 var file = new Blob([data.data], {
                    type: 'application/octet-binary'
                });
                var fileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                // for IE 10+
                if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
                    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file, fileName+'.'+documentExt);
                } else {
                    var element = document.createElement('a');
                    element.href = fileUrl;
                    element.setAttribute('download', fileName+'.'+documentExt);
                    element.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
                    document.body.appendChild(element); 
                    element.click();
                }
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        }
```

Comment: Hey Shaliendra, well server side is not problem cause for example this api call that i am pointing to when i am calling this function : https://localhost:8080/download?fileId=workspace%3A%2F%2FSpacesStore%2F09d8bd7c-03d7-411d-9ded-d825d86b19e9%3B1.0

if I put this in browser directly and try to open file that is downloaded in word it is working it is nor corrupted.